# How do I merge two datasets in python, so that the data in each row is also merged?

Tags: python, list, merge

I am scraping names on a website that has the names split up into first name and last name. I have a list with first names and a list with last names that I want to merge into one list with full names.

For example I could have a list with first names:

Rishi, Boris, Theresa

And a list with last names:

Sunak, Johnson, May

How do I merge the lists with the end result being:

Rishi Sunak, Boris Johnson, Theresa May

(This would be a list with 1 row and 3 columns)

I tried to merge them using pandas, but it did not work.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(uni_firstname)
df1 = df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]: "Name" })
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(uni_lastname)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={df2.columns[0]: "Lastname" })

uni_name = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=(df1), right_on=(df2))
```

This gave me:

```
KeyError:      Lastname
0     Akcigit
1     Behrman
2      Bohren
3     Akcigit
4     Behrman
..        ...
71       Todd
72     Wolpin
73   Yamamoto
74     Wolpin
75   Yamamoto

[76 rows x 1 columns]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if both `first_name` and `last_name` are equal in length you can use `zip` function..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both list equal in length. With lists:

```
[uni_firstname[i] + ' ' + uni_lastname[i] for i in range(len(uni_firstname))]
```

With DF:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(uni_firstname, columns=['name'])
df1['lastname'] = uni_lastname
df1['fullname'] = df1['name'] + ' ' + df1['lastname']
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing the inbuilt [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: first_names = ['Rishi', 'Boris', 'Theresa']
   ...: last_names = ['Sunak', 'Johnson', 'May']

In [3]: full_names = [f'{first} {last}' for first, last in zip(first_names, last_names)]

In [4]: full_names
Out[4]: ['Rishi Sunak', 'Boris Johnson', 'Theresa May']

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'full_names': full_names})

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
      full_names
0    Rishi Sunak
1  Boris Johnson
2    Theresa May
```